# Use environment variable in Python Sphinx image directive

Tags: environment-variables, python-sphinx

I have a Python project with [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/) documentation, and to keep the code repository small, some of the images and other files I want to include in the docs are in a separate repo.

For the Sphinx docs build, I do have a shell environment variable set to point to the other repo. I tried using it from an [image directive](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#images) like this:

```
.. image:: $OTHER_REPO/docs_images/image.png
```

but that doesn't work.

For now, I've put some code in `docs/conf.py` that copy over the files I need into the `docs` source tree, and then it works. But this feels like a hack, there must be a proper / better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution that solves my problem.

Visit [Change variable in sphinx conf.py as part of build command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216495/change-variable-in-sphinx-conf-py-as-part-of-build-command)

Basically, we can define the env variable in Jupyter that can initialize in the **make.bat** file by set the following comments:

### Jupyter notebook:

```
try:
    status_flag = %env status_flag
    print('Status_flag defined as ' + status_flag + '!')
    
except:
    status_flag = 'MP4'
    print('Status_flag defined as ' + status_flag + '!')
```

### make.bat:

```
SET status_flag=HTML
%SPHINXBUILD% -M %1 %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %O%
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I know its been over 7 years the question was asked but the last days I faced the same issue and solved it as followed. Maybe it helps some others in the future

**Long Story short:** Use rst substitution with rst_prolog in conf.py

- https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions
- https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_prolog

**Example**

Lets assume the following project directory:

```
ROOT
|-docs
|   |-dummy_pic.png
|-docs_sphinx
|   |-source
|       |-conf.py
|-dummy_pkg
    |-test_module.py
```

Add the following setup to conf.py (rst_prolog)

```
import os

# first approach: environment variables
dummy_png = os.path.join(os.environ["OTHER_REPO"], "dummy_pic.png")

# second approach via absolute path
ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# set docs folder
docs_folder = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(ROOT, "..", "..", "docs"))
# set dummy path
dummy_png = os.path.join(docs_folder, "dummy_pic.png")

# updates slashes
dummy_png = dummy_png.replace("\\", "/")

# set rst_prolog
# define absolute file path --> based on https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_epilog
rst_prolog = f"""
.. |dummy_png| image:: {dummy_png} 
    :height: 11
"""
```

Afterwards, use the substitution in your docstring. In this case, it is located in test_module.py

```
def test_func():
    '''
    |dummy_png|
    '''
    pass
```

And this should do the trick. At least it solved my issue. Further I want to try if it works with other files as well.