# Change variable in sphinx conf.py as part of build command

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a Sphinx project with a `conf.py` in which I use a variable to specify my product name as below:

```
device_name = "ProductName"
rst_epilog = f".. |device_name| replace:: {device_name}"
```

I would like to be able to modify the value of ProductName during my build process as part of my `.bat` file as I'm building the same project twice, once for each of my two products:

```
sphinx-build  -t ce2 -b html -d _build_ce2/doctrees source _build_ce2/html -E
sphinx-build  -t ce1 -b html -d _build_ce1/doctrees source _build_ce1/html -E
```

Is there a way to modify the `conf.py` variable `device_name` directly in the build command?

Comment: Maybe try this option https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-D or others?

Comment: That option looks like what I need, though when I try to parse it I get an error. My build line incl. this looks as follows: `sphinx-build  -t ce2 -b html -d _build_ce2/doctrees source _build_ce2/html -E -D device_name="ProductName2"` - but it states `WARNING: unknown config value 'device_name' in override, ignoring`

Comment: It seems I can use the `-D` option to modify e.g. my release version - but not "new custom" variables that I've created, like e.g. my product name. Is there some way to get around this?

Comment: It is possible to register a custom configuration variable (see https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_config_value). However, I was not able to override it from the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving this using environment variables.

**conf.py**

```
# get environment variables (set as part of make .bat files)
env_device_name = os.getenv("DEVICENAME")

# set device name
if env_device_name != None:
    device_name = env_device_name
else:
    device_name = "CANedge2"  # default device name
```

**make.bat**

```
SET DEVICENAME=Product2
sphinx-build  -t ce2 -b html -d _build_ce2/doctrees source _build_ce2/html -E
SET DEVICENAME=Product1
sphinx-build  -t ce1 -b html -d _build_ce1/doctrees source _build_ce1/html -E
```

Comment: shorter alternative could be `env_device_name = os.getenv("DEVICENAME", "CANedge2")`